# How to count the children (elements) inside a fieldgroup?

Tags: 7, entities

I use the [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module in a website and I'm trying to count the fields within a Field Group.

I tried …

```
$num_of_fields = count($content['group_name']['children']);

echo $num_of_fields;
```

… but it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following code you will see the value that you need.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {      
   //you need the devel module to use dpm() function
  //My field group name is group_g2
  dpm(count($form['#groups']['group_g2']->children));
}
```

Is easy to track values if you use the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and [Search Krumo](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_krumo) modules

Comment: Thanx Adrian! I'll try to get along with your solution.

Comment: @LarsD Let me know if you have problems or if you find the solution.

Comment: @LarsD do you get some advance?